# Weird results with xml query in sql -server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

This is my `xml query`

```
declare @x xml=N'';
select @x.query('(1,2,3,4)=1') --1 /* Returns True */
select @x.query('(1,2,3,4)!=1')--2 /* Returns True...how is this possible*/
```

for the first case the value is `True` because atomic value in left sequence is equal to 1(left atomic value)

But for second case also its `True` How is this possible i was expecting a false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Comparison Expressions (XQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190935.aspx):

> When you are comparing two sequences by using general comparison
>   operators and a value exists in the second sequence that compares True
>   to a value in the first sequence, the overall result is True.
>   Otherwise, it is False. For example, (1, 2, 3) = (3, 4) is True,
>   because the value 3 appears in both sequences.

`(1,2,3,4)=1` is equivalent to `(1,2,3,4)=(1)` in this case `1` exists in the first sequence so it's `TRUE`. Though for `2,3,4` it's `FALSE` BUT using the above rule if for at least one element condition is `TRUE` then OVERALL result is `TRUE`.

`(1,2,3,4)!=1` is equivalent to `(1,2,3,4)!=(1)` we have `1` from the second sequence and it's compared `TRUE` (with `!=`) to the element of the first sequence `2` or `3,4` so we get overall result - `TRUE`.

More examples:

```
(1,2,3,4)>3  - TRUE (4 > 3)
(1,2,3,4)<3  - TRUE (1,2 <3)
(1,2,3,4)<5  - TRUE (1,2,3,4 < 5) 
(1,2,3,4)>5  - FALSE (There is no element from the first sequence > 5 )
```

So if for at least one element condition is TRUE then overall result is TRUE.

Think about it as `OR`:

```
(1,2,3,4)!=1 => (1!=1) OR (2!=3) OR (3!=3) OR (4!=3)
```